# What are the concepts or family of concepts fundamental to being and existence?

Tags: ontology

What are the concepts or family of concepts fundamental to being and existence? I understand that this can be subjective, but I am interested in the opinion of famous philosophers on this question. One of the concepts should be space, and there are others, but I don't want to name them all, I am wondering if philosophers have identified more then 2-3 of these concepts or family of concepts fundamental to being and existence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For brainstorming in general, particularly if there is no need for something authoritative, [language models](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transformer_(machine_learning_model)) can provide many ideas and sometimes insights. GPT-NeoX (see *Model* dropdown) at the [TextSynth Playground](https://textsynth.com/playground.html) is one readily accessible option.

For example, I gave this prompt:

> The following ontological concepts are fundamental to being and existence:
>
> 1. Space.
> 2. 

Which gave the below list, among others (with minor formatting by me):

> 1. **Space** (including the possibility of vacuum and infinite space).
> 2. **Time** (from its smallest and fastest units to its largest and slowest units).
> 3. **Matter** (from the smallest units of energy to the largest units of energy).
> 4. **Consciousness** (from non-existing to the most intelligent).
> 5. **Language** (from non-existing to the most expressive, encompassing and complete human languages).

Indeed, extraneous entries sometimes happen, but these can help in coming up with new ideas. Different language models have different training and inference capacity, tending to give different results. A more powerful model is [GPT-3](https://openai.com/), but it requires sign-in and has limited free credits (as of my knowledge at this writing). Changing the prompt can also make a big difference. Adding names or other references can set the context, and additional information can be requested, as for example:

> According to Whitehead, ontological fundamentals include

Replacing various names in the above prompt can give some curious ideas.